# JavaScript script replaces strings only when a local variable is defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, wordpress, for-loop, webpack

This is how the script works:

1. Reads `manifest.json` file which contains file names
2. Reads `functions.php` file to `result` variable
3. Loops through `pages` array. Within each iteration, creates regular expressions
4. Strings matching the regular expressions are searched for in `result` variable. If a match is found, it is replaced with similar string from `manifest.json`
5. Result variable is written to `functions.php` file

**Script:**

```
      const manifest = fse.readJsonSync("./dist/manifest.json");

      fse.readFile("./functions.php", "utf8", function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
        let result;
        for (let [i, page] of pages.entries()) {

          // page = "index";

          const scriptsRegEx = new RegExp(`/dist/scripts.${page}.+?'`, "g");
          const cssRegEx = new RegExp(`/dist/styles.${page}.+?'`, "g");
          result = data
            .replace(scriptsRegEx, `/dist/${manifest[`${page}.js`]}'`)
            .replace(cssRegEx, `/dist/${manifest[`${page}.css`]}'`);
        }
        fse.writeFile("./functions.php", result, "utf8", function (err) {
          if (err) return console.log(err);
        });
        console.log(result);
     });
```

**The issue:**

If I run the script as is, no string gets replaced inside `functions.php`. However, if I uncomment the `page = "index"` line inside the loop, strings get replaced inside `functions.php`. In short, the loop doesn't work. What could be the reason?

Comment: Well, it appears that `for (let [i, page] of pages.entries())` isn't setting `page` to what you want it to be so your script only does something when you manually set it to `"index"`.  Add a `console.log(page)` and see if it's actually the right thing.  Even if it is what you expect it to be, then apparently the RegExp you are constructing are not matching anything in the file.

Comment: I've tried console logging page variable and also the regular expression. The variable carries correct regularexpression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One main problem is that inside your loop, you're doing:

```
 result = data.replace(...).replace(...)
```

Since `.replace()` does not modify `data`, this means that each time through your loop, you start with a the original version of `data` and ONLY the last time through the loop ever ends up affecting the final value of `result`.  If the last time through the loop doesn't actually find anything to replace, then you end up just writing the original contents back to the same file and nothing changes.

You could fix that by doing:

```
 data = data.replace(...).replace(...)
```

And then writing out the final value of `data`.  This way each time through the loop modifies the result of the previous iteration through the loop rather than starting over with the original content each time.